# any suggestion for help me to fix bootstrap navbar mobile not working On PC/Laptop works well but on any Phone the bar is auto close

Tags: css, content-management-system

Toggle navigation
                
              
                    Toggle navigation

```
            <div class="search-login">

                 <form method="get" id="header-searchform" action="/">
                        <input type="search" autocomplete="off" name="s">
                        <input type="hidden" name="post_type[]" value="portfolio" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="post_type[]" value="post" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="post_type[]" value="page" />
                        <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                </form>
            </div>

            <div class="menu-main-container">

                <ul id="main_menu" class="nav navbar-nav group navbar-collapse collapse">

                    {{ navigationWidgetPServerCore().menu('default').setPartial('p-server-core/navigation')|raw }}

                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div id='magic-line'></div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-inner -->
    </nav>
```

any help? all works well on pc laptop but on phone bar is auto close.